# iOS & MVC - How to create this app/game

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm really quite confused as to how I'm supposed to implement the following app. I have 90% of the code, but the last 10% I can't figure out. I can't figure out how I'm supposed to control the flow of events. I'll describe the app/game first.

### The Game

The flow of events happens like this. The user sets the number of teams and the number of rounds. The game will then show a screen saying "Pass to team 1". The player on team 1 then presses a button which pushes on another view.

On this view, the current player tries to describe words/names on the screen to the other players on their team without saying them. Each time someone guesses a word/name correctly, the player presses a button which pulls out more words, and adds 1 to the score for that team. This continues until a timer runs out.

When the timer has ran out, this view will get popped off the navigation controller, and the previous view will tell the player to pass to team 2.

This will loop for the number of teams and the number of rounds.

### My Problem

My problem is that I really don't understand how I'm supposed to keep track of all these events. I have a "GameBrain" class where I keep an array of scores and team names etc. but I don't know how to access this from each ViewController.

I asked a similar question earlier and someone suggested a Singleton class, but I've since read that this is bad practice and I can't help but feel that I *should* be able to do this following the MVC design pattern.

So my question is, how would you guys/girls approach coding a game like this?

Sorry for the kind of vague question. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Are delegates the correct way to go? i.e. Would I create the first ViewController that I need from my "GameBrain", set the brain (so `self` in this case) as the delegate for this instance, and have the ViewController call a "I'm done with this round" method on the brain which would then fire off the next ViewController?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your GameBrain should be designed as a singleton, singletons may have some bad sides, but in your case they are the best choice, so just go with it

Since this class has to be accessed by all your viewControllers and since there is no need of having multiple instances of this class, then this would fit a singleton perfectly

Answer (score 1):

I started with a comment but moved on to an answer.

In short, as @Omar says, for a quick little thing you describe the Singleton may work fine.

The longer version, several years ago I designed a quick little thing like this and we released it and all was well. Several months later we had several million users and had undergone multiple development phases and the Singleton pattern we had begun with was destroying the project. I might mention that my boss insisted at the beginning it was a small project and we would release it in two weeks and be done - hah, funny guy.

The reason the Singleton did not work well is because it restricted modularity. In the end, everything "game related" had to come back through this class which in turned sent a message to another class which sent a response back to the Singleton etc. etc. It was horrible.

If you have the time/energy, I recommend you create a GameBrain (or whatever) class for each game. This class is usually only ever used in the "game screen" anyway, so why keep it around when you are back in the menu or sending emails? If you need it persistent the make it backed by a database. If you only need it in one or two extra places (your winning screen might need to know who won etc.), just pass it along by reference - you should only need to do it one or two times.

Good luck.

Comment: So are you saying that this is an inherent problem for singletons? That using singletons in general is bound to be a problem to modularity? I have to strongly disagree - there are many more factors to consider here. I do understand how bad design can lead you to use the singleton pattern in a wrong way but I don't think that you will necessarily create something that is not robust, scalable and modular just because you chose to separate logic and data via singleton.

Comment: In this application, why does it need to be Singleton? Surely you can play many games? Where is the single-ness? To me, the problems arise from this already - like you say it starts as a bad design. I don't understand your point about login and data via singleton?

Comment: Sorry, meant logiC :) The main point is that while this is debatable for this specific problem, it's not correct to say that singletons are bad for modularity.

Comment: Ok agreed. I don't know where I made that generalization

Comment: Thanks for the input both. It's all helping a lot to getting me on to fully understanding this stuff. I suppose I will need my brain to be visible to a total of 3 views. So if I don't go with a singleton, will I create a brain in ControllerA, then pass my brain instance to ControllerB, and then on to Controller C?